# Mod-Rewrite and .htaccess Problems

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having some issues with Mod_Rewrite. I must admit this is my first venture into the module so I could be going through something silly. I have been trying to get this to work on my own for a day or so off and on and I can not figure out why this is not working.

I am getting the following errors:

**Notice: Undefined index: Dir in D:\wamp\www\WildForFashion\Portal\Index.php on line 31**

What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to have one template page (index.php) and have Mod_Rewrite change the url for me so it can be Search Friendly and to also ease coding and design.

I was also having issues when it came to no Images / CSS files loading at all, I did read that by using an absolute url would work.

As of right now I am working in the PORTAL directory first (which is an admin page for website maintenance) and then will be moving onto the root directory. I am not sure if I need to have one .htaccess file or two (one being in root dir, second being in portal dir).

The DIR folder is to hold each category and page for the website like the following:

```
Domain.com/{CATAGORY}/{PAGE}/
ROOT / DIR / {CATAGORY} / {Page}.php

Domain.com/Portal/{CATAGORY}/{PAGE}/
ROOT / Portal / DIR / {CATAGORY} / {Page}.php
```

#### .htaccess Before

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/Portal/$      Portal/Index.php?Dir=Portal&Page=Home   [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^Portal/(.*)/(.*)$  Portal/Index.php?Dir=$1&Page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^Portal/(.*)/$      Portal/Index.php?Dir=$1&Page=Home   [L,QSA]
```

#### .htaccess After (Working w/ Exceptions)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule Portal/$     Portal/Index.php?Dir=Portal&Page=Home   [L,QSA]
RewriteRule Portal/([^/]+)/$     Portal/Index.php?Dir=$1&Page=Home   [L,QSA]
RewriteRule Portal/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$     Portal/Index.php?Dir=$1&Page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

#### Index.php

```
<?php
include_once("DIR/" . $_GET['Dir'] . "/" . $_GET['Page'] . ".php");
?>
```

#### Directory Tree

> - CSS
> - DIR
> - IMG
> - JS
> - SRC
> - Portal
>
>   - CSS
>   - DIR
>
>     - Portal
>     - Inventory
>     - Stats
>     - Orders
>   - IMG
>   - JS
>   - SRC
>   - Index.php
>   - .htaccess
> - Index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including forward slashes in the matching rule that don't need to be there and excluding them from the redirect path where they do need to be. Try this:

```
RewriteRule Portal/$      Portal/Index.php?Dir=Portal&Page=Home   [L,QSA]

RewriteRule Portal/(.*)/(.*)$  Portal/Index.php?Dir=$1&Page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule Portal/(.*)/$      Portal/Index.php?Dir=$1&Page=Home   [L,QSA]
```

Note I removed the ^ from the matching portions of the rewrite rules as this indicated taht should be the beginning of the URI. I also removed the "/" in front of the substritution pattern.

Comment: Tried, Restarted Apache for Kicks, and Nothing.

http://localhost/WildForFashion/Portal/ ==> Gives Me Same Error
http://localhost/WildForFashion/Portal/Inventory/ ==> Gives me a 404

Comment: Have yo been able to verify that requests in each of the formats shown in the rewrite rules are actually routing to the Index.php file correctly?  If you can you do a var_dump of the $_GET value.  Also would be helpful to see some real-world examples of the URL's you are using

Comment: var_dump($_GET['Dir']);

var_dump($_GET['Page']);

Both returns null and I get a 'Notice: Undefined index:'

Comment: Let's try this.  Can you change all the [L,QSA] values to [R=301,L,QSA] temporarily.  I want to make sure the rewrites are actually happening.  This will break your clean URL's for a minute, but will give you positive feedback that you are indeed getting the correct URL rewrites, as you will see the URL change in your browser. Try all three URL formats you are trying to use.

Comment: http://localhost/WildForFashion/Portal/ ==> Null for Var_Dump and I do not see anything changing in the URL Box

http://localhost/WildForFashion/Portal/Inventory/ ==> 404 ( /WildForFashion/Portal/Inventory was not found on this server)

Comment: OH.. so there is is a WildForFashion portion of the URI that wasn't mentioned before. OK sorry about that.. let me update teh answer above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14486/discussion-between-jon-h-and-mike-brant)

Comment: I was able to get it to work, See Original Post in the .htaccess file. I had to move the .htaccess file to the root dir for it to work, if I move it into the Portal folder it will not work, any reason why?

Comment: It could depend on the AllowOverride settings for the directories in Apache config.  Would need to see your entire Apache config to fully understand why.